# Fill collection in a proteced constructor of a derived class

Tags: .net

I am looking for a way to fill a Collection in the Constructor of a derived Class. What I have is:

```
Public Class cls1
Private myCol as new List(of String)

Protected Sub New(ByRef Col as List(Of String))
myCol = Col
End Class


Public Class cls2
Inherits cls1
'here I want to fill my list with some strings
'e.g. mycol.add("Hello")
Sub New(col)
mybase.new(...)
End Class
```

I tried:

```
    Public Class cls2
    Inherits cls1
    Private colSet as new List(of String)

    Sub New()
    colSet.Add("Hello")
    mybase.new(colSet)
    End Class
```

But this is not working. Any help realizing what I am looking for would be great?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Class `cls1`, change it to this:  `Protected myCol as new List(of String)`.  It could be as simple as this, if this is what you want:

```
Public Class cls1
    Protected myCol As New List(Of String)
End Class

Public Class cls2
    Inherits cls1

    Sub New()
        myCol.Add("Hello")
    End Sub
End Class
```